# saving to multiple models from one form with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model-associations

i have been getting into rails over the course of the last couple weeks and i've run across a problem that I can not find the answer to. i feel like this is probably something really simple but it's driving me crazy so I am hoping to get a little bit a guidance...

I am inserting data from 1 form into 2 models. one model is called Venue and one model is called Events. It is a one to many association where multiple events belong to venues and venues have many events.

models:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue

  scope :upcoming, where('date >= ?', Date.today)
 end
```

controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

def new
      @venue = Venue.new
end

def create

@venue = Venue.new(params[:venue])

    if @venue.save
        render :inline => "Success"
    else
        render('new')
    end
end

end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for(@venue, :url =>{:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

        Artist ID<br />
        <%= fields_for :event do |event_fields| %>
            <%= event_fields.text_field :artist_id %><br/><br />
        <% end %>

        Venue City<br />
        <%= f.text_field(:city) %> <br /><br />
        Venue Name<br />
        <%= f.text_field(:name) %><br/><br/>


        <div class="actions">
            <%= submit_tag "Save", :class => "btn primary" %>
        </div>

<% end %>
```

log output:

```
Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-17 19:57:24 -0500
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"p3llx5KsYn6gyjP9g2qwzXr+0rjh3h/o34h/iqvqjRo=", "event"=>{"artist_id"=>"124"}, "venue"=>{"city"=>" Boston", "name"=>"Bostons Fa'v"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "venues" ("address_1", "address_2", "capacity", "city", "country", "created_at", "created_by", "name", "state", "updated_at", "url", "zip") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["address_1", nil], ["address_2", nil], ["capacity", nil], ["city", " Boston"], ["country", nil], ["created_at", Sat, 18 Feb 2012 00:57:24 UTC +00:00], ["created_by", nil], ["name", "Bostons Fa'v"], ["state", nil], ["updated_at", Sat, 18 Feb 2012 00:57:24 UTC +00:00], ["url", nil], ["zip", nil]]
(0.4ms)  COMMIT
Rendered inline template (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

As you can see its not failing but it is only submitting to the 1 model. My understand is that by adding "accepts_nested_attributes_for :events" the Venue model knows to then go to my Events table, create a new event with the event data I provide (in this example just artist_id), and then automatically insert the id field from my venue table into venue_id.

The more I think about this here the more I think I might be missing a step and....If anyone has a second I would appreciate hearing your thought process on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error in the form. The fields_for is a method of f and it expects a plural symbol. It is also a good practice to have the iterator of a block in singular, and not to use parentheses when your method only expects one parameter:

```
<%= form_for(@venue, :url =>{:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

        Artist ID<br />
        <%= f.fields_for :events do |event_field| %>
            <%= event_field.text_field :artist_id %><br/><br />
        <% end %>

        Venue City<br />
        <%= f.text_field :city %> <br /><br />
        Venue Name<br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %><br/><br/>


        <div class="actions">
            <%= submit_tag "Save", :class => "btn primary" %>
        </div>

<% end %>
```

See this example of a nested form in [Ryan Bate's Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?):

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <% f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <p>
    <%= builder.label :content, "Question" %><br />
    <%= builder.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so I added the "f." in front of the fields_for and made events plural. when i reload my form a text_field is not generated. to you does this insinuate that the model is not properly set up and its not finding the relation between venue and event? it failed to generate with both event and events just FYI. thanks

Comment: i have a feeling my problems have to do with my routes probably being incorrect, i am looking into that now.

Comment: With a resource for each model it should be working. I recommend that you watch the screencast I posted, Ryan's explanations are very simple to follow

Comment: thank you that was a big help, I should have watched that screencast the first time. Appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it =), what was the problem specifically? I recommend that you mark an answer as accepted so this question can be considered as solved.

Comment: Just did, thanks....A combination of a few things between routing issues & missing @Venue = venue.event.build in my controller's new action. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`Venue` model needs to specify which attributes are mass-assignable, including `Event` attributes.

```
attr_accessible :event_attributes, :address_1, :address_2, :capacity # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response...still having some trouble though..I changed it to below but I am still seeing the same issue.   // class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :event_attributes, :id, :address_1, :address_2, :capacity, :city, :country, :created_at, :created_by, :name, :state
  has_many :events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
end